# How to hide/remove the default minimize/maximize buttons on window developed with Kivy?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, kivy

How I can remove or hide the default minimize or maximize button of a window created with kivy.

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but you can remove entire titlebar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613738/how-can-i-hide-the-main-window-titlebar-and-place-a-transparent-background-in-ki

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a simple way to do this - it's not exposed in the kivy window api, and may not even be exposed in pygame (which is likely the backend you're using on desktop).

Maybe you can look up the right way to do it on each system you target, e.g. I think you can hint it to X11, but I don't know if this is really plausible or nice.

We're developing a new sdl2 backend, which is more flexible about some of these kinds of things, but I don't know if it would make this possible.

Comment: Are there any updates on this question? Is there a way to do it now?

Answer (score -1):

First option:

(Seen on https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2616)

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', 'True')
```

.....

Second option:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.bordeless = 'True'
```